# Intro to algorithms Big O Notation

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics

Hi I'm trying to read the book Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition
[https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-3rd-MIT-Press/dp/0262033844](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262033844)
And i having problem understanding the math in Chapter 3(Growth of a functions) pages 54-53
i cant solve any exercises in the book what I need to learn to understand it                and to be able to solve the exercises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this video :

[link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdmmEEWyZlg

A function $f(x)=x^2$ increases faster than the function $f(x)=x^2/2$.

In the same way $f(x)=x^2$ does not increase as fast as $f(x)=2*x^2$.

But ignoring the constants(c which are 1,1/2 and 2), 
all the three functions grow asymptotically at the same rate. 

Hence if there exist constants c1,c2 and m such that:

$0<=c1*g(n)<=f(n)<=c2*g(n)$ for all $n>=m$, 

$\theta(g(n))=f(n)$

Note that $f(n)$ here is a set of functions. Not only one single function.

Comment: what is max (f (n),g(n)) ?